# Remove index.php from URL in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have done this lots of time. But than also I am stuck here again (in a different server)  and can not figure out what is the issue.

Completed htaccess editing

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /glt.me/CI/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /glt.me/CI/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

- rewrite module is enabled (as per customer care perons says)
- Error :

  Internal Server Error

  The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

  Please contact the server administrator, cgiadmin@yourhostingaccount.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

  More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

  Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Test this case :

```
http://glt.me/CI/test
http://glt.me/CI/index.php/test
```

Comment: You need to check your error logs to see what caused it

Comment: @JonLin - Guessing is more fun. Checking logs is like reading documentation: only the weak do it ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the simple way and it works fine for removing index.php from your url

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|uploads|css|js|lib|img|bootstrap|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /manage/index.php/$1 [L]

instead of manage put your own application folder name.
```

Comment: Worked. Removed domain from RewriteRulke line.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /CI/index.php?/$1 [L]

Comment: I've tried this code 
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`
But still I can view the page in both way 
http://www.domain.com/about-us , 
http://www.domain.com/index.php/about-us and
http://www.domain.com/index.php?/about-us

Comment: which generating SEO error i.e duplicate title tag and duplicate meta description

Answer (score 2):

Use following htaccess code to remove index.php from your codeigniter url

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Though your client confirmed the rewrite module is working, what don't you confirm it yourself, make a php file on the root of the project with the code below and try to browse the file.

```
<?php
 if( !function_exists('apache_get_modules')){
        echo 'Rewrite module not available';
 }else{
    if(in_array('mod_rewrite',apache_get_modules()))
        echo 'Rewrite module enabled';
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

First check whether your apache is supporting `mod_rewrite`. If yes then add a `.htaccess` file. My codeigniter .htaccess file is:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Finally in your config file, change your base_url, remove index.php from that if you have added.

Answer (score 0):

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^pages/.*$ http://localhost/test/? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to contribute here as I was having trouble myself. I'm using IIS5.1 for development only (Highly not recommended!)

1- Make sure that you config.php file has:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

2- My app is not on the root folder, it's at localhost/CodeIgniter/. I updated config.php to:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/CodeIgniter/';
```

3- You need Mod-Rewrite capabilities. This is embedded with most servers, but IIS5.1 needs a separate tool. I used: IIS Mod-Rewrite by micronovae. It's free as long as you use it on localhost

I put the following code (Instead of CodeIgniter, put the name of the folder):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $0 !^/CodeIgniter/(css|js|swf|images|system|tools|themes|index\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/CodeIgniter/(.*)$ /CodeIgniter/index.php/$1 [L]
```

If your application is at the root, the code you should use would be simply:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $0 !^(css|js|swf|images|system|tools|themes|index\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Only three steps are require to remove index.php from url in Codeigniter in WAMP environment.

1) Create .htacess file in parallel to application holder and just copy past the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /CodeIgniter/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

2) Change $config['index_page'] to blank in config.php in application folder as below:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

3) Enable “rewrite_module” of apache.

Restart your apache and its done.

Details : http://sforsuresh.in/removing-index-php-from-url-of-codeigniter-in-wamp/